# Is there a way to make numpy work with Maya 2020?

Tags: python, numpy

I have Python 3.9.1 with numpy 1.19.4 install, and Maya 2020. I have installed a plug-in (SMPL, actually, from here: https://smpl.is.tue.mpg.de/downloads), loads without any problems, but errors when it hits the first line that actually references numpy ('''np.array()'''...) with the error being this:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'array'
```

I suspect I may be using a version of numpy that Maya does not like. Has anybody else come across this? Any hints on how to resolve would be most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Do `print(np)` and `print(dir(np))` on it line above. What is the result?

Comment: The result is: 

`<module 'numpy' from 'C:\Users\Yannis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\numpy'>`

which is what I expected.

for `print(dir(np))` the result is:

`['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`

Comment: Definitely looks like the module isn't loading properly. There should be more stuff in it

Comment: Follow that path. What's in the numpy folder?

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved! Thanks @mad-physicist for nudging me towards the correct direction.

The issue boiled down to requiring a maya-compatible build of numpy, to be pip-installed under the specific python instance (mayapy.exe) that ships with the Maya installation.

The details here: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-programming/numpy-2018-2019/td-p/9349010

It is supposed to be for Maya 2018 and 2019, but it worked just fine with my 2020 installation too.